# Migrate full table to json/clob column in another table

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I want to migrate the data from following **table1**:

```
NAME | Surname
-----+---------
Name1| Surname1
Name2| Surname2
```

Into **table2**  as a clob (nclob,nvarchar(max),json.. etc.) column:

```
NAME | JSON_COLUMN
-----+-------------------------------
NAME1| {Name: Name1,Surname: Surname1}
NAME2| {Name: Name2,Surname: Surname2}
```

I wonder what is the best way to do this type of migration ?

Is there a function that can convert a table into json format so I can insert it into the new table?

Something like this:

```
insert into table2 (JSON_TABLE) select (table1 as json) from table1
```

Comment: Your question is tagged multiple database products and the answer depends on which you are using as well as the version. Narrow your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman need a general solution for all if possible

Comment: @MasterYi: JSON functions are highly vendor specific, so there is no *generic solution* to this question. As commented by Dan Guzman, you should pick the most relevant databse.

Comment: @GMB ok I will leave oracle only then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle 12c and higher, You will need to convert the column values using `JSON_OBJECT` and then to `CLOB` and for proper JSON use `FORMAT JSON` (SQL string values `'true'` and `'false'` are converted to the `JSON Boolean` values `true` and `false`.)

Example:

> ```
> SQL> WITH TABLE1 AS (
>   2      SELECT 'Name1' NAME, 'Surname1' SURNAME FROM DUAL
>   3      UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT 'Name2', 'Surname2' FROM DUAL
>   5  )
>   6  SELECT
>   7      NAME,
>   8      TO_CLOB(JSON_OBJECT ( 'Name' VALUE NAME,
>   9                    'Surname' VALUE SURNAME
>  10                    FORMAT JSON )) AS "JSON_TABLE"
>  11  FROM
>  12      TABLE1;
>
> NAME      |JSON_TABLE
> ----------|--------------------------------------------------
> Name1     |{"Name":"Name1","Surname":Surname1}
> Name2     |{"Name":"Name2","Surname":Surname2}
>
> SQL>
> ```

For Oracle 11g and lower, you need to create the JSON by yourself as follows:

> ```
> SQL> WITH TABLE1 AS (
>   2      SELECT 'Name1' NAME, 'Surname1' SURNAME FROM DUAL
>   3      UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT 'Name2', 'Surname2' FROM DUAL
>   5  )
>   6  SELECT
>   7      NAME,
>   8      to_clob('{"Name:"' || NAME || '","Surname":'||SURNAME || '}') as "JSON_TABLE"
>   9  FROM
>  10      TABLE1;
>
> NAME      |JSON_TABLE
> ----------|--------------------------------------------------
> Name1     |{"Name:"Name1","Surname":Surname1}
> Name2     |{"Name:"Name2","Surname":Surname2}
>
> SQL>
> ```

Another option in Oracle 11g is to use sql*plus command-line interface as following:

```
set sqlformat json
```

and then `SELECT * FROM TABLE1` will generate the json format result but you need to export it to some file using `spool` and then load it into `TABLE2`. (Might be Lengthy approach)

Cheers!!

Comment: Also have to rename the / \ and ' characters, if they exists they make the json not valid.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle, you can use `json_object()`:

```
select 
    name,
    json_object('Name' value name, 'Surname' value surname) js
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=52b819ba35ac8c5012a7a96d08a40e31)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select 'Name1' name, 'Surname1' surname from dual
    union all select 'Name2', 'Surname2' from dual
)
select 
    name,
    json_object('Name' value name, 'Surname' value surname) js
from mytable
```

```
NAME  | JS                                   
:---- | :------------------------------------
Name1 | {"Name":"Name1","Surname":"Surname1"}
Name2 | {"Name":"Name2","Surname":"Surname2"}
```

Comment: works fine for oracle 12.2+, on 12c1 ORA-46099: Feature unsupported or not implemented, I guess I have to manually create the json in select.

Comment: @MasterYi: indeed, json support was added in Oracle 12.2 relased in 2016.